# What is the name of the "triple quoted string" property in vscode."editor.tokenColorCustomizations"

Tags: visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, in the "settings.json" file, I am editing a color theme, and need a way to describe the property for triple quoted strings seen in functions as comments:

```
    "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Starfall Palenight]": {
        "comments": "#82bdd1",
        "strings": "#75ec9d"
    }
},
```

The attempt to use "comments" fails, as this property only applies to real comments, and "strings" only affects normal strings.

An example of what my desired comment would look like is shown below:

```
def func(): 
'''this is the comment explaining how the function works'''
pass
```

Thank you

Comment: they are **not comments**, they are strings that are being misused as "comments" because they are expressions, for comments the language has other syntax `#`, it is a documentation string used for the `help` command in REPL, and tooltips in VSC, it should not explain **HOW** the function works, should be done in a comment, but it should explain HOW to use it and WHAT it does, what it does should be clear from the name of the function

Comment: the textmate scope clearly tells you want it is (not a comment): `string.quoted.docstring.multi.python`

Comment: Where is the documentation for all this, please?